# Attach listener to Socket.IO added content

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm loading in some data with Socket.IO and adding it to a table with a JS function inside the Socket.io listener. At the end of each row of that table, I'm trying to add a button that gets the content in the newly added row and does something with it. However, the event handler isn't firing for the newly added button. I feel that I am properly attaching `on()` to the parent and have tried every variation of this, but I still can't get the button to fire. Here's my code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn btn-warning', function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});

socket.on('loadtable', function (table) {
            $("#tableBody").append('<tr><td>' + table["name"] + '</td><td>' + table["id"] +
            '</td><td>' + table["loc"] + '</td><td>' + table["area"] + '</td><td>' + table["zip"] +
             '</td><td><a href="#editModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>'
             + '</td><td><input type = "checkbox"></td></tr>'
            );
        });

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id ="jobsTable">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class = "span2">Name</th>
                    <th class = "span2">Process</th>
        <th class = "span2">JAR</th>
        <th class = "span1">Main Class</th>
        <th class = "span2">Args</th>
        <th class = "span1">Edit</th>
        <th class = "span1">Select</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id = "tableBody">
</tbody>
```

Am I overlooking something with the way the inside of a Socket function works?

Comment: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: I've tested on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn.btn-warning', function() {
```

Comment: Works! Seems that was an improper way to select the class. Such a small problem. Thanks for pointing it out!